# Unpad / remove borders from filtered image

Tags: image, border, filtering, matlab

I applied a Gabor filter of a specific size and orientation to a greyscale Image. So i get new  filtered image by using the 2-D convolution "conv2". I saw some persons who tried to remove the borders from the filtered image, in other words, to unpad the filtered image. What does these borders ?

For example:

```
    %if length(amount==1) , unpad equal on each side.
    %if length(amount==2) , first amount is left right, second amount is up down.
    %if length(amount==4) , then [left top right bottom].

switch (length(amount))
case 1
sx=size(i,2) - 2 * amount;  % i is the filtered image
sy=size(i,1) - 2 * amount;
left=amount + 1;
right=size(i,2) - amount;
top=amount + 1;
bottom = size(i,1) - amount;

case 2
sx=size(i,2) - 2 * amount(1);
sy=size(i,1) - 2 * amount(2);
left=amount(1) + 1;
right = size(i,2) - amount(2);
top= amount(2) +1;
bottom = size(i,1) - amount(2);

case 4
sx=size(i,2) - (amount(1) + amount(3));
sy= size(i,1) - (amount(2) + amount(4));
left = amount(1) + 1;
right = size(i,2) - amount(3);
top = amount(2) + 1;
bottom = size(i,1) - amount(4);

otherwise
error('illegal unpad amount\n');

end
```

I didn't understand this code, what are the left, right, top and bottom ? do they differ from sx and sy ?? please can someone help me and explain to me in details what happens in this code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In linear convolution (implemented by `conv2`), the filtered image gets some margins at the edges, sort of "noise", becuase of the way the convolution works. This function delete these margins (maybe to get the original size of image, depends on the value of `amount`) , while:

`amount`- size of margins.

`sx`- new number of columns.

`sy`- new number of rows.

`left`- the column number where the new image starts.

`right`- the column number where the new image ends.

`top`- the row number where the new image starts.

`bottom`- the row number where the new image ends.

So, you can get the new image from this: `NewI=i(top:bottom,left:right);`

**EDIT**: (for the comment's questions)

Suppose you want to reamove `amount` columns from each side, say 5. So, the total columns you remove is 10. So the new number of columns is the original number (`size(i,2)`) minus 10 (`2*amount`). The same for the rows number.

Because you want to remove 5 columns from left, the first columns that remains is the 6th one, so now the left border will be at 6 (`amount+1`). This is also the idea for the rest (right, top, bottom)

Comment: And why sx=size(i,2) - 2 * amount ? why 2*amount ? ,,,,and why left=amount + 1; ?? please can you explain to more about each case in the code. So you can update your answer :) Thank's in advance

Comment: Does this problem appear only with 2-D convolution ? what about 1-D convolution ? we don't have added margins by using 1-D convolution ?

Comment: It happens in both 1-D and 2-D convolutions. Actually, 2-D convolution is separable, so one can represent it by production of two different 1-D convolution: one for each dimension. So you get margins in both width and  height.